# How can I improve this small program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def multiply():
    nums = []
    total = 1
    multiplyCount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to multiply ? : "))
    for x in range(multiplyCount):
        newNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        nums.append(newNum)
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        total *= nums[x]
    print(total)

multiply()
```

Here's my code. I want to make it not ask for multiplyCount but instead keep adding numbers to multiplyCount until the user decides it's enough. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You could go with something like this:

```
total = 1
while True:
    choice = input('Enter a number to be multiplied, or stop to terminate: ')
    if choice.lower() == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        total *= int(choice)
        print('Current total is {}'.format(total))
    except ValueError:
        print('Only enter numbers or stop')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example do it with a `while`-loop, like this:

```
def multiply():
    nums = []
    total = 1
    while True:
        newNum = input("Enter quit or a number: ")
        if newNum.lower() == "quit":
            break
        else:
            nums.append(int(newNum))
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        total *= nums[x]
    print(total)

multiply()
```

There are many additional ways to further improve on this, but I'll leave that to you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! But I didn't understand what newNum.lower() does here. Can you explain that ?

Comment: @Fingol it will convert the user's input string to all lowercase letters. So that the user can enter 'Quit' or 'QUIT' or 'quiT' etc to end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The best way is to use a sentinel value, it is up to the user to enter a specific value if he wants to stop. In the following code, the sentinel value to enter to complete is 'Q'. It can obviously be modified according to the choice of the programmer, but it is disadvised to choose an integer / boolean for this case (to allow the user to multiply any value).

(2) Also, a variable can be used instead of your list. (x*=y means x=x*y)

(3) The variable res is initialized to 1 because this integer is neutral in the multiplication.

```
def multiply():
    res, number = 1, 1
    while number != 'Q':
        res *= int(number)
        number = input("Enter a number (Q for leave): ")
    print(res)
```